# How to use jiffies in linux?

Tags: linux, clock, timing

I understand what jiffies are and how to get the values in linux but I don't understand the purpose of it and how this value could be used ? Why do we even need it in the first place ? Could someone please explain to me ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's just how we measure the time since the system booted. It avoids having to do floating point calculations when updating the uptime, which could also introduce round-off error that cascades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By and large, you don't need to use jiffies. They're an implementation detail of how the Linux kernel keeps track of time, and somewhat obsolete at that. Quoting `man 7 time`:

> **The software clock, HZ, and jiffies**
>
> The accuracy of various system calls that set timeouts, (e.g.,
> `select(2)`, `sigtimedwait(2)`) and measure CPU time (e.g.,
> `getrusage(2)`) is limited by the resolution of the software clock, a
> clock maintained by the kernel which measures time in jiffies.  The
> size of a jiffy is determined by the value of the kernel constant
> `HZ`.
>
> ...
>
> **High-resolution timers**
>
> Since Linux 2.6.21, Linux supports high-resolution timers (HRTs),
> optionally configurable via `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS`.  On a system
> that supports HRTs, the accuracy of sleep  and timer  system  calls
> is no longer constrained by the jiffy, but instead can be as accurate
> as the hardware allows (microsecond accuracy is typical of modern
> hardware).

Instead of using jiffies, just use the higher-level calls like `gettimeofday(2)` which work in more standardized units like seconds.